# Equals method implementation for arrays - Java

Tags: java, equals, overwrite

I'm surprised this `equals` method works.. even though it's using `.equals` which does not exist in its old form anymore since I've overwritten it..?

What I mean is, if you look at the code, to compare the two array elements I'm using `.equals`.

But.. if I'm overwriting the equals method, wouldn't `.equals` just use my overwritten method?
I'm a little confused, I would really appreciate some explanation as to how that works.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof arrayClass) {
        arrayClass that = (arrayClass) other;
        if (this.number == that.number) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.number; i++) {
                if (this.elements[i].equals(that.elements[i])) {

                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: `number` represents the arrays length.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `elements`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: But the two array elements you are comparing are not the same as the objects you are comparing (`this` and `that`) with your implementation of `equals` so it is another implementation of `equals`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm surprised this equals method works.. even though its using .equals which does not exist anymore in it's old form anymore since I've overwritten it

You've overridden the `equals` method for `arrayClass` class. Inside your implementation of `equals` you are calling `equals` for the elements of the array, which means you are calling the `equals` method of the class which is the element type of the `elements` array. For example, if `elements` is a `String[]`, `elements[i].equals()` calls `String`'s `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

The equals call inside the for loop is not invoking your equals implementation. Your implementation is over the Array class, and the equals inside the for loop is invoking the equals implementation for whatever class type you are storing in the array.

Also, this piece of code is not optimized. You can remove the empty block inside the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.number; i++){
    if (!this.elements[i].equals(that.elements[i])) {
          return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: re: the "also" suggestion. I'd be quite surprised if ```if (something) { } else { return; }``` was compiled to code less efficient than ```if (!something) { return; }```.  Mind you, I agree the second form is desirable - but this is for the benefit of the reader, not the computer.

Comment: Hehe, I understand you. Of course the bytecode won't change. But think about test cases, PMD, checkstyle. It makes the difference. Maybe the word "optimized" was not the best word to pick.